# Calaculating Quartely cash collections

Tags: financing, cash-flow, collections

Sorry if this is the wrong place for this financial concept question, it's about the cash budget.

Accounts receivables at the beginning of the year are $345. The company has a 60 day collection period. Calculate cash collection in each of the four quarters.

```
Q1: 820
Q2: 850
Q3: 930
Q4: 1010
```

So in the case of a 45 day collection period I know that we must first calculate **beginning cash + 1/2 * sales**

We multiplied the sales by half because 45 days is a half quarter, so for a 60 day collection period it should be multiplied by 2/3 but that is wrong from what my professor told us as the correct way would be by 1/3.

I'm confused, can someone explain this part for me? Why is it 1/3 and not 2/3? Same thing for a 30 day receivable period.

Comment: Think about it this way - with a 60-day collection period, only the sales in the first 30 days (1/3) of the quarter will be collected in that quarter - the rest will be collected in the next quarter.

Comment: But they said in the first 60 days will be collected, why is it in the first 30 days?

Comment: No that means it _takes_ 60 days to collect (on average) so if you make a sale on day 31, it will not get collected until day 91 (the first day of the next quarter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collection occurs n days after sale, if n is 60:

```
Day of Sale     Day Collected
1               61
2               62
3               63
...
29              89
30              90
31              91
```

Only the first 30 days will be collected in the 90 that comprise the quarter. Take the difference between days in the quarter and collection period first:
`(90-60)/90 = 1/3`.